# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-beautiful-dnd'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-beautiful-dnd'. The problem is with this module. I am writing to do list, everything must work, but I see the error. Dont have any idea how it can be fixed. I tried to delete and download modules and update npm, but it did not work. Somehow react does not see modules at all for some reasons.
Package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.45",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.2"
  }
}
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { DragDropContext, Draggable, Droppable, DropResult } from "react-beautiful-dnd"
import "./App.css"

const listItems = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Study Spanish"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Workout"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Film Youtube"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    name: "Grocery Shop"
  }
]

const getItemStyle = (isDragging: boolean, draggableStyle: any) => ({
  padding: 10,
  margin: `0 50px 15px 50px`,
  background: isDragging ? "#4a2975" : "white",
  color: isDragging ? "white" : "black",
  border: `1px solid black`,
  fontSize: `20px`,
  borderRadius: `5px`,

  ...draggableStyle
})

function App() {
  const [ todo, setTodo ] = useState(listItems)

  const onDragEnd = (result: DropResult) => {
    const { source, destination } = result
    if (!destination) return

    const items = Array.from(todo)
    const [ newOrder ] = items.splice(source.index, 1)
    items.splice(destination.index, 0, newOrder)

    setTodo(items)
  }
  return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Drag and Drop</h1>
        <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
          <Droppable droppableId="todo">
            {(provided) => (
                <div className="todo" {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
                  {todo.map(({ id, name }, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Draggable key={id} draggableId={id} index={index}>
                          {(provided, snapshot) => (
                              <div
                                  ref={provided.innerRef}
                                  {...provided.draggableProps}
                                  {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                  style={getItemStyle(snapshot.isDragging, provided.draggableProps.style)}
                              >
                                {name}
                              </div>
                          )}
                        </Draggable>
                    )
                  })}
                </div>
            )}
          </Droppable>
        </DragDropContext>
      </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: It's not listed in your dependencies. [Perhaps try installing it?](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/about/installation.md#general)

Comment: As @Andy said you should add react-beautiful-dnd in dependencies list  by installing it via npm command `react-beautiful-dnd`

Answer (score 4):

The module is not listed in the list of installed dependencies meaning it's not installed as a dependency for the application. You can try to run `npm i react-beautiful-dnd` and this will add the dependency to your node modules.